# Spring Neo4J REST error - nodeStateTransmitter

Tags: java, spring, rest, neo4j, spring-boot

I've been trying to get this simple example running (with java 1.7) https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-accessing-neo4j-data-rest/tree/master/complete

I keep getting the following error when attempting to start the application via the main method in the Application class.

I'uploaded the entire log to this gist: http://bit.ly/1hU7Vpu

Here's the summary of the error.

```
WARN 6470 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Error handling failed (Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.setBeanFactory(Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactory;)V)
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityFetchHandler' defined in class hello.Application: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jEntityFetchHandler org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration.entityFetchHandler() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'nodeStateTransmitter' defined in class hello.Application: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you are seeing a Spring version conflict. See the following line in your error log:

```
exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.setBeanFactory(Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactory;)V)
```

You should be able to prevent this error by removing the following line (you might not need it anyway):

```
@Import(RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class)
```

Can you show the output of `mvn dependency:tree`? There might be duplicate Spring libs on your classpath.

EDIT:

It appears that it's the snapshot release of SDN that's causing the issue. Use

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

instead of

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

You might have found a bug!

Comment: Removing the @Import(...) line leads to another error.

Comment: And what exception do you get?

Comment: The error is 2014-03-24 07:41:34.328  INFO 6632 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service Tomcat
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityFetchHandler' defined in class hello.Application: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jEntityFetchHandler org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration.entityFetchHandler() ....

Comment: Yes, changing the version to  3.0.1.RELEASE fixes the errors!! I'll raise a github issue. How did you determine that the spring data version was responsible for the errors that I described? Thanks

Comment: I tried out your Github project and started playing around. When I see SNAPSHOT somewhere in a build file, I always revert to the latest stable release, just to be sure.